# Microsoft SQL given ANY DATE find out if AFTER specific month and day

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server-2008

I don't use SQL everyday so bear with me ... I need to find out if the date has passed a certain month and day period. If this is not clear let me give you an example:

Ex: Given a date: 2012/02/08 (2012 Feb 08) determine if it is after 07/01 (Jul 01) in this case NO.

I need some kind of generic query to check if any given full date (SQL format `smalldatetime`) to see if it is AFTER 07/01. Basically ignoring the year part only verifying based on Month and Day.

Solution: Here is how I used it in a query

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[databaseName] 
WHERE DATEPART(mm, RCVD_DATE) >= 7 and DATEPART (DD, RCVD_DATE) >= 1
```

Will only give you results that have received date that are on 7/1 or after (ignoring the year).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select table.column from table 
where DATEPART(mm,table.column)>=7
and DATEPART(DD,table.column)>=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script that lets you do the test.  The important part is the conditional in the case statement.  Use that where you need to do the test.

```
declare @date datetime
set @date = '2/8/2012'

select case when @date > cast('7/1/' + cast(year(@date) as varchar(10)) as datetime) then 'yes'
            else 'no'
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

Only Month part will also work in this case.

```
Declare @smallDate smalldatetime 
Set @smallDate='2012/02/08'
IF (DATEPART(MM,@smallDate))>=7
select 1
else
select 0
```